# Automatically restore windows network drive (red "X") via batch file

Tags: windows, network-share, batch

i need check if a network drive is mapped and accessible. From time to time windows displays a red X on the drive, and i would need to manually click the drive in explorer to reconnect. 
I already found solutions which involve editing the registry which unfortunately isn´t possible.

So i would need a batch file checking for connection, and (re-)mounting the drive. What i´m using at the moment:

```
IF NOT EXIST z: net use z: \\10.211.55.5\test
```

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve?

Answer (score 1):

Just an idea, how about attempting to `cd` into the network share from within the batch script? I suspect that should connect and update the state of the network share for explorer to show that it is connected.

I suspect the registry solutions were something like the following article?

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/297684

If you can't use the registry however, try the above and see if that re-establishes connection to the network share.